# Find if two columns exist in another table, matched as a pair

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I've seen some other questions about comparing multiple columns, but I'm not sure they fit this exact need.

I'm trying to ensure an exact pair of columns in one table exists as the exact same pair of columns in another table. The goal is to check and mark a bit column as true false if it exists.

The last part of this script returns a 1, but I'm not sure if the logic ensures the exact pair is in the second table.

Is the logic in the last part of the script comparing both tables correct?

[image: Multiple table image]

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #t1
 (
      courseid     VARCHAR(10)
     ,courseNumber VARCHAR(10)
 )

 INSERT INTO #t1(
    courseid
   , courseNumber
 )
 VALUES
    (3386341, 3387691)

 CREATE TABLE #t2
 (
     courseid       VARCHAR(10)
    ,courseNumber   VARCHAR(10)
    ,CourseArea     VARCHAR(10)
    ,CourseCert     VARCHAR(10)
    ,OtherCourseNum VARCHAR(10)
 )

 INSERT INTO #t2(
     courseid
   , courseNumber
   , CourseArea
   , CourseCert
   , OtherCourseNum
 )
 VALUES
    (3386341 , 3387691 , 9671 , 9671 , 233321)
   ,(3386341 , 3387691 , 9671 , 9671 , 233321)
   ,(3386342 , 3387692 , 9672 , 9672 , 233322)
   ,(3386342 , 3387692 , 9672 , 9672 , 233322)
   ,(3386343 , 3387693 , 9673 , 9673 , 233323)
   ,(3386343 , 3387693 , 9673 , 9673 , 233323)


   SELECT 
   CASE WHEN courseid IN (SELECT courseid FROM #t1) AND courseNumber IN (SELECT courseNumber FROM #t2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsCourse
   FROM #t1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always opt for an *exists* correlation here as it's faster and NULL-safe

```
select
    case when exists (
      select * from #t2 t2
      where t2.courseid = t1.courseId and t2.courseNumber = t1.courseNumber
    ) then 1 else 0 end IsCourse
from #t1 t1;
```

Comment: Thank you for you help!  I am grateful you took the time to help me!  Should parenthesis be added to the where clause?

Comment: *parenthesis* - what do you mean, in the query above? If so, no; never add parethesis unless functionally necessary.

Comment: @JM1 you typically only need brackets if you are combining `AND` with `OR` so that you can combine the logic correctly.

Answer (score 2):

No, your query doesn't correlate the id & number so your query will return a positive if the id exists anywhere in t2 and the number exists anywhere in t2, but doesn't confirm they exist on the same row. You want `EXISTS` e.g.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #t2 t2
        WHERE t2.courseid = t1.courseid
        AND t2.courseNumber = t1.courseNumber
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsCourse
FROM #t1 t1;
```